# Open MPI can't launch remote nodes via SSH

Tags: ssh, cluster, hpc

I am trying to set up Open MPI between a few machines on out network.
Open MPI works fine locally, but I just can't get it to work on a remote node.
I can ssh into the remote machine (without password) just fine, but if I try something like

```
mpiexec -n 4 --host remote.host hello_c
```

then the ssh connection just times out.

I checked several tutorials but the only configuration instructions they give is "make sure you can ssh into the remote machine without a password". I did and I still can't launch nodes on remote machines. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the remote machine are you able to ssh to other machines and localhost without password? If not, you may not have copied over your private key. Are your systems running something like SELinux or AppArmor? For SELinux you can run 'setenforce 0' to disable it so you can test.